# Torch squeeze and the batch dimension

Tags: pytorch, torch

does anyone here know if the `torch.squeeze` function respects the batch (e.g. first) dimension? From some inline code it seems it does not.. but maybe someone else knows the inner workings better than I do.

Btw, the underlying problem is that I have tensor of shape `(n_batch, channel, x, y, 1)`. I want to remove the last dimension with a simple function, so that I end up with a shape of `(n_batch, channel, x, y)`.

A reshape is of course possible, or even selecting the last axis. But I want to embed this functionality in a layer so that I can easily add it to a `ModuleList` or `Sequence` object.

EDIT: just found out that for Tensorflow (2.5.0) the function `tf.linalg.diag` DOES respect batch dimension. Just a FYI that it might differ per function you are using

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No! squeeze doesn't respect the batch dimension. It's a potential source of error if you use squeeze when the batch dimension may be 1. Rule of thumb is that only classes and functions in torch.nn respect batch dimensions by default.

This has caused me headaches in the past. **I recommend using `reshape` or only using `squeeze` with the optional input dimension argument.** In your case you could use `.squeeze(4)` to only remove the last dimension. That way nothing unexpected happens. Squeeze without the input dimension has led me to unexpected results, specifically when

1. the input shape to the model may vary
2. batch size may vary
3. `nn.DataParallel` is being used (in which case batch size for a particular instance may be reduced to 1)

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer is sufficient for the problem - to `squeeze` last dimension. However, I had tensor of dimension `(batch, 1280, 1, 1)` and wanted `(batch, 1280)`. `Squeeze` function didn't allow for that - `squeeze(tensor, 1).shape` -> `(batch, 1280, 1, 1)` and `squeeze(tensor, 2).shape` -> `(batch, 1280, 1)`. I could have used `squeeze` two times, but you know, aesthetics :).

What helped me was `torch.flatten(tensor, start_dim = 1)` -> `(batch, 1280)`. Trivial, but I forgot about it. Warning though, this function my create a copy instead view, so be careful.

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html